# Android Map with webview?

Tags: android

In my application i have segmented control on Segment change  i inflate layout and In inflated layout have Webview ...

Now i want to display map with current lat-long and Two destination lat-long with Pin....

Mind that Without map activity and there I cant call any Implicit intent and also not new actiity........

Any Map Url Just pass two location and see Pin and map is Zoom properly without drawing path.......Mind that Just two location with Pin not Directions .............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this google static map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#MarkerStyles) you can pas two parameter and push pin on map...

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&maptype=roadmap\
&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7CSan+Francisco,CA%7COakland,CA%7CSan+Jose,CA&sensor=false
```